# Read a csv with numpy array using pandas

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

I have a `csv` file with 3 columns `emotion, pixels, Usage` consisting of `35000` rows e.g. `0,70 23 45 178 455,Training`.

I used `pandas.read_csv` to read the `csv` file as `pd.read_csv(filename, dtype={'emotion':np.int32, 'pixels':np.int32, 'Usage':str})`.

When I try the above, it says `ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '70 23 45 178 455'`? How do i read the pixels columns as a `numpy` array?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please try the below code instead -

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, dtype={'emotion':np.int32, 'pixels':str, 'Usage':str})

def makeArray(text):
    return np.fromstring(text,sep=' ')

df['pixels'] = df['pixels'].apply(makeArray)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. It now says `TypeError: data type not understood`. What could be the probable mistake?

Answer (score 2):

It will be faster I believe to use the vectorised [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) method to split the string and create the new pixel columns as desired and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) the new columns to the new df:

```
In [175]:
# load the data
import pandas as pd
import io
t="""emotion,pixels,Usage
0,70 23 45 178 455,Training"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t))
df

Out[175]:
   emotion            pixels     Usage
0        0  70 23 45 178 455  Training

In [177]:
# now split the string and concat column-wise with the orig df
df = pd.concat([df, df['pixels'].str.split(expand=True).astype(int)], axis=1)
df
Out[177]:
   emotion            pixels     Usage   0   1   2    3    4
0        0  70 23 45 178 455  Training  70  23  45  178  455
```

If you specifically want a flat np array you can just call the `.values` attribute:

```
In [181]:
df['pixels'].str.split(expand=True).astype(int).values

Out[181]:
array([[ 70,  23,  45, 178, 455]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and figured out a hack. Save your datafrae as a `.npy` file. While loading it, it will be loaded as an `ndarray`. You can the use `pandas.DataFrame` to convert the ndarray to a dataframe for your use. I found this solution to be easier than converting from string fields. Sample code below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.save('file_name.npy',dataframe_to_be_saved)
#the dataframe is saved in 'file_name.npy' in your current working directory

#loading the saved file into an ndarray
arr=np.load('file_name.npy')
df=pd.DataFrame(data=arr[:,1:],index=arr[:,0],columns=column_names)

#df variable now stores your dataframe with the original datatypes
```