# reading dataframe from csv and array problems

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe

The application I use generates data in a dataframe which I need to use upon request.

It looks similar to this.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
             E         Gg        gnx2    J chs lwave J_ID
0    27.572025  82.308581    7.078391  3.0   1   [0]    1
1    46.387728  77.029548   58.112338  3.0   1   [0]    1
2    75.007554  82.087407    0.535442  3.0   1   [0]    1
```

Everything worked perfectly while I didn't try to use dataframes saved in separate files before. Because when I am trying to use the data after loading - I got errors about data types for the columns which contain arrays.
(lvawe for example) is an array and when saved in csv the information about data type is lost.

```
#saving the data to csv
csv_filename = "ladder.csv"
ladder.to_csv(csv_filename)
```

So when loading a dataframe next time to use the data I can't get access to array elements like it should.

Because as I understand data in this column is loaded like string.
After loading the data through load_csv I get this for the data types:

```
Unnamed: 0      int64
E             float64
Gg            float64
gnx2          float64
J             float64
chs             int64
lwave          object
J_ID            int64
dtype: object
```

How can I resolve this issue? How can I correctly load the data with the correct data type or maybe explicitly assign a data type to a column after loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was resolved by the use of json.loads feature.

```
#modifying the ladder using json

modified = ladder_df.lwave.apply(json.loads)
ladder_df['lwave'] = modified
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `read_csv` function, you can manually assign data types to your new columns. Pass in a dictionary of column name --> preferred data type.

```py
data_type_mapping = {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32, ‘c’: ‘Int64’}
my_df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', dtypes = data_type_mapping)
```

From `pandas` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> *Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32, ‘c’: ‘Int64’} Use str or object together with suitable na_values settings to preserve and not interpret dtype. If converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion.*

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. It seems correct, but I don't know how to apply it in my case.
The code I have tried is listed below.

Comment: Tried to use this one, @StonedTensor,


data_type_mapping = {...   'lwave': np.ndarray, 'J_ID': np.int64 }

filename = isotope_name + '_Emin_10_Emax_1000_2022.10.30_ladder.csv'
resonance_ladder = pd.read_csv(filename, dtype = data_type_mapping)

But I am having error :

TypeError: dtype '<class 'numpy.ndarray'>' not understood

I don't get which dtype I need to use..

Comment: What is an example of what `lwave` is supposed to look like? What is its type _before_ you save the dataframe originally?

Comment: sorry for my bad understanding of stackoverflow :) I don't get how to add code or markup in the comments. Here is an example of the data in lwave column [1.0, 1.0]

Comment: The data types before  saving looks like this: print(resonance_ladder.dtypes) 
E        object
...
chs      object
lwave    object
J_ID     object
dtype: object

Comment: @twistfire try adding `object` as the type when you do the mapping. I wonder if it'll recognize it should be an array from there...

Comment: tryed to use this mapping: data_type_mapping = {
    'E': np.float64,
    'Gg': np.float64,
    'gnx2': np.float64,
    'J': np.float64,
    'chs': np.int64,
    'lwave': np.object,
    'J_ID': np.int64
    }. Got the same error:     if orbital_angular_momentum > 3:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.str_' and 'int'

Comment: pandas just assuming that this object type is numpy.str_?

Comment: what is `orbital_angular_momentum`? Does this happen on loading the CSV?

Comment: no, it happens during data processing - on the next stage. When row data is compared to the orbital_angular_momentum variable which is also calculated based on the leave column of a dataframe. And the problem is the elements of that column load as strings, not as list of numbers... That's why this error occurs but I don't get how to provide the format to the pd.read_csv to have an array with numbers in a dataframe column but not a string object...

Comment: Last comment before we move to a different chatroom, but you _cannot_ do this in the _read_csv_ function, but can do it by writing a custom function that loads a `numpy` array from a string. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30930895/6023918) out.